# Knockout observable property is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js plugin in my application. I have a problem with observable. I created an [Example Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/agaxuw/3/edit). In this fiddle i am creating `Menus` dynamically and generating `Menu sequence` each time when new menu is added. User can to delete any existing menu also except first one.

The problem comes when user delete any existing menu. Because at the time of deletion i am updating the sequence number in the remove function but the sequence numbers are not updating.
Can anybody please tell me whats the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining the Sequence variable. Originally it is a ko.observable. You are setting it to a integer value. You should set the value as so

```
newMenuVM.Sequence(self.menus().length+1);
```

This will allow the observable to notify and update the value on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/agaxuw/5/edit)

**Modified:**

```
newMenuVM.Sequence = ko.observable(self.menus().length+1);

self.menus()[i].Sequence(i+1);
```

**Deleted:**

```
self.courseOptions.push(newMenuVM);
```

**Reason:**

When I run your fiddle, I see an error "Property 'Sequence' of object # is not a function".

I search this property and see:

```
newMenuVM.Sequence = self.menus().length+1;
```

So, I add **ko.observable** function.

Comment: JNo thanks a lot for help. If you can explain the cause then it will really help me a lot in future

Comment: I am confused here because i made Sequence property observable in MenuViewModel then why again it is necessary to make it observable

Comment: See others changes too, courseOptions property is undefined and in Sequence property you should add +1.